# Slow network traffic with DNS only after migrating Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS to airgapped network

Tags: networking, dns, ping, active-directory

I have two networks in my environment, a main network and an offline/air-gapped network. The standard process for deploying Ubuntu servers to the air-gapped network is to clone a template VM on the main network, run a few preliminary scripts, mostly just for pre-downloading any packages, then export it as an OVF&VMDK, then import it to the air-gapped network and run a few more scripts to install the pre-downloaded packages and realm join it to the Active Directory domain.

I first noticed the problem when I attempted to log into the server using an AD account and the login just kinda timed out. Didn't throw and errors or anything; it just went back to the login screen. This happens around 50% of the time. Other times it works just fine, if not a little slow to authenticate. The other thing I notice is that pinging another host *by hostname* on the network takes a really long time - around 10 seconds per ping, but the rtt shows normal times. Pinging another address by IP is normal.

My first guess was that it had the DNS servers from the main network stuck somewhere, but everything I can find points to the correct DNS servers handed out by DHCP. What I am seeing is a lot of generic (at least to me) SERVFAIL responses in a tcpdump capture and the DNS server logs.

Here is a tcpdump output from the vm, looking at port 53:

```bash
root@ubuntu-vm:~# tcpdump -i ens160 port 53
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on ens160, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
09:07:32.105888 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35510 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [F.], seq 4076711660, ack 1840100910, win 502, length 0
09:07:32.106333 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35510: Flags [.], ack 1, win 8212, length 0
09:07:32.106374 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35510: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 8212, length 0
09:07:32.106399 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35510 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 2, win 502, length 0
09:07:32.186940 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].58620 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:07:34.844633 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35161 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 35926+ [1au] A? [FQDN-of-Pinged-Host]. (65)
09:07:34.844845 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].42108 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 42780+ [1au] AAAA? [FQDN-of-Pinged-Host]. (65)
09:07:34.845573 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].35161: 35926* 1/0/1 A [IP-of-Pinged-Host] (81)
09:07:34.845620 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].42108: 42780* 0/1/1 (124)
09:07:37.106115 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [S], seq 3439429067, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2320413146 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
09:07:37.106501 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [S.], seq 2277878216, ack 3439429068, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:07:37.106565 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:07:37.106714 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 1:49, ack 1, win 502, length 48 41254+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:07:37.116854 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [.], ack 49, win 8212, length 0
09:07:37.191912 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 49:95, ack 1, win 502, length 46 7563+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:07:37.210637 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [.], ack 95, win 8212, length 0
09:07:42.197494 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 95:143, ack 1, win 502, length 48 2292+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:07:42.211682 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [.], ack 143, win 8212, length 0
09:07:43.529020 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].49395: 41254 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:07:43.529075 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].58620: 7563 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:07:47.202643 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].57047 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:07:47.202744 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].58263 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 41254+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:07:52.208224 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].46243 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 19986+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:07:52.208405 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].53989 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 2292+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:07:52.208479 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 143:191, ack 95, win 502, length 48 41254+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:07:52.208615 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 191:237, ack 95, win 502, length 46 7563+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:07:52.208902 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [.], ack 237, win 8211, length 0
09:08:02.356033 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].42788 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 41254+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:02.356137 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38255 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:03.462460 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].46243: 19986 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:03.462558 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].53989: 2292 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:04.436588 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [P.], seq 143:191, ack 331, win 8211, length 48 41254 ServFail 0/0/0 (46)
09:08:04.436657 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 191, win 502, length 0
09:08:04.436963 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [P.], seq 191:237, ack 331, win 8211, length 46 7563 ServFail 0/0/0 (44)
09:08:04.436988 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 237, win 502, length 0
09:08:07.356028 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].36576 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 2292+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:07.356147 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38735 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 19986+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:07.356248 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 331:342, ack 237, win 502, length 11 [prefix length(0) != length(9)] (invalid)
09:08:07.356285 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 342:388, ack 237, win 502, length 46 7563+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:08:07.356392 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 388:436, ack 237, win 502, length 48 41254+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:08:07.356534 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [.], ack 388, win 8211, length 0
09:08:07.356573 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].37976: Flags [R.], seq 237, ack 388, win 0, length 0
09:08:07.356728 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33302 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 41254+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:07.356781 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].32989 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:12.606191 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [S], seq 3401119311, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2320448646 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
09:08:12.606621 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970: Flags [S.], seq 719780311, ack 3401119312, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:08:12.606685 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:08:12.606809 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 1:49, ack 1, win 502, length 48 2292+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:08:12.606878 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 49:95, ack 1, win 502, length 46 7563+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:08:12.606912 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 95:189, ack 1, win 502, length 94 [prefix length(44) != length(92)] (invalid)
09:08:12.607082 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970: Flags [.], ack 95, win 8212, length 0
09:08:12.625092 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970: Flags [.], ack 189, win 8212, length 0
09:08:13.423947 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33302: 41254 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:13.424002 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].42788: 41254 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:13.424084 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].32989: 7563 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:13.424089 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38255: 7563 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:19.782990 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38735: 19986 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:19.783049 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].36576: 2292 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:22.856071 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].44185 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 2292+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:22.856169 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [F.], seq 189, ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:08:22.856246 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].40176 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 41254+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:22.856297 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38621 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 19986+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:22.856346 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].53304 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:22.856450 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970: Flags [.], ack 190, win 8212, length 0
09:08:22.856503 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 190, win 8212, length 0
09:08:22.856527 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].56970 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 2, win 502, length 0
09:08:28.106217 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [S], seq 895705459, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2320464146 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
09:08:28.106647 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518: Flags [S.], seq 3811087542, ack 895705460, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:08:28.106701 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:08:28.106775 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 1:49, ack 1, win 502, length 48 2292+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:08:28.106837 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 49:143, ack 1, win 502, length 94 [prefix length(44) != length(92)] (invalid)
09:08:28.106894 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 143:189, ack 1, win 502, length 46 19986+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:08:28.107065 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518: Flags [.], ack 143, win 8212, length 0
09:08:28.127687 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518: Flags [.], ack 189, win 8212, length 0
09:08:34.300649 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].40176: 41254 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:34.300718 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].44185: 2292 ServFail 0/0/1 (57)
09:08:34.300727 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].53304: 7563 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:34.300736 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].38621: 19986 ServFail 0/0/1 (55)
09:08:38.356034 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].40895 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 2292+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:38.356131 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [F.], seq 189, ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:08:38.356206 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33940 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 19986+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:38.356259 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].41961 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 41254+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (57)
09:08:38.356339 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].40465 > [IP-of-DNS-Server01].domain: 7563+ [1au] PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (55)
09:08:38.356366 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518: Flags [.], ack 190, win 8212, length 0
09:08:38.356408 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 190, win 8212, length 0
09:08:38.356423 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].48518 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 2, win 502, length 0
09:08:43.606178 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [S], seq 1485297616, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2320479646 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7,tfo  cookiereq,nop,nop], length 0
09:08:43.606595 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056: Flags [S.], seq 4145950509, ack 1485297617, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
09:08:43.606661 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, length 0
09:08:43.606824 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 1:49, ack 1, win 502, length 48 2292+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:08:43.606913 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 49:95, ack 1, win 502, length 46 7563+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server02].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:08:43.606959 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 95:141, ack 1, win 502, length 46 19986+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-DNS-Server01].in-addr.arpa. (44)
09:08:43.607000 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [P.], seq 141:189, ack 1, win 502, length 48 41254+ PTR? [reversed-IP-of-Pinged-Host].in-addr.arpa. (46)
09:08:43.607053 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056: Flags [.], ack 95, win 8212, length 0
09:08:43.607118 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056: Flags [.], ack 189, win 8212, length 0
09:08:45.289639 IP [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain > [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056: Flags [P.], seq 1:42, ack 189, win 8212, length 41 52101 ServFail 0/0/0 (39)
09:08:45.289707 IP [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM].33056 > [IP-of-DNS-Server02].domain: Flags [.], ack 42, win 502, length 0
^C
97 packets captured
108 packets received by filter
11 packets dropped by kernel
```

Here are filtered debug logs from the DNS server:

```
DNS Server log file creation at 1/30/2024 7:59:11 AM
Log file wrap at 1/30/2024 7:59:11 AM

Message logging key (for packets - other items use a subset of these fields):
    Field #  Information         Values
    -------  -----------         ------
       1     Date
       2     Time
       3     Thread ID
       4     Context
       5     Internal packet identifier
       6     UDP/TCP indicator
       7     Send/Receive indicator
       8     Remote IP
       9     Xid (hex)
      10     Query/Response      R = Response
                                 blank = Query
      11     Opcode              Q = Standard Query
                                 N = Notify
                                 U = Update
                                 ? = Unknown
      12     [ Flags (hex)
      13     Flags (char codes)  A = Authoritative Answer
                                 T = Truncated Response
                                 D = Recursion Desired
                                 R = Recursion Available
      14     ResponseCode ]
      15     Question Type
      16     Question Name
1/30/2024 7:59:43 AM 0A84 PACKET  0000013709A60B50 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] f32d   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)[pinged-hostname](6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:43 AM 0AD0 PACKET  00000137183E82E0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 0ab9   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] AAAA   (8)[pinged-hostname](6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:43 AM 0A84 PACKET  0000013709A60B50 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] f32d R Q [8085 A DR  NOERROR] A      (8)[pinged-hostname](6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:43 AM 0AD0 PACKET  00000137183E82E0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 0ab9 R Q [8085 A DR  NOERROR] AAAA   (8)[pinged-hostname](6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:43 AM 0AD0 PACKET  00000137183FB750 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 7:59:45 AM 0AD0 PACKET  00000137183E82E0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 4da1   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] AAAA   (6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:45 AM 0A84 PACKET  00000137183B7170 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 478d   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:45 AM 0AD0 PACKET  00000137183E82E0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 4da1 R Q [8085 A DR  NOERROR] AAAA   (6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:45 AM 0A84 PACKET  00000137183B7170 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 478d R Q [8085 A DR  NOERROR] A      (6)[subdomain2](7)[subdomain1](8)[domain](3)[tld](0)
1/30/2024 7:59:53 AM 0A84 PACKET  000001371839B8D0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 7:59:54 AM 0DC0 PACKET  00000137183FB750 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 7:59:54 AM 0DC0 PACKET  00000137183FB750 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 7:59:54 AM 0A84 PACKET  000001371834F990 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:05 AM 0A84 PACKET  000001371839B8D0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:06 AM 0DC0 PACKET  000001371834F990 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:06 AM 0DC0 PACKET  000001371834F990 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:06 AM 0A84 PACKET  00000137184430C0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:17 AM 0A84 PACKET  0000013718445CD0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:18 AM 0DC0 PACKET  00000137184430C0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:18 AM 0DC0 PACKET  00000137184430C0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:18 AM 0A84 PACKET  000001371839B8D0 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:29 AM 0A84 PACKET  00000137183FB750 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 9101   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:30 AM 0DC0 PACKET  000001371839B8D0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 9101 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:30 AM 0DC0 PACKET  000001371839B8D0 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] bf46 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:30 AM 0A84 PACKET  000001371834F990 UDP Rcv [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 9101   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
1/30/2024 8:00:43 AM 0DC0 PACKET  000001371834F990 UDP Snd [IP-of-Ubuntu-VM] 9101 R Q [8281   DR SERVFAIL] PTR    (3)[host-octet](3)[subnet-octet3](3)[subnet-octet2](3)[subnet-octet1](7)in-addr(4)arpa(0)
```

My best guess is that some configuration from the main network it was built on stuck around somewhere, but at this time, I have not been able to find it.